# Can I read private SSH key without knowing its type with paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I'm authenticating to remote server with `paramiko.SSHClient` by SSH key. For it I have several configs for different servers with paths to SSH keys. And it happened so that some of them are Ed25519 and some are RSA. Connecting with just password is not an acceptable option.

At first I wanted to connect with the following code:

```
keyfilename = build_configuration['sshPrivateKeypath']
keyfilename = os.path.expandvars(keyfilename)
key = paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file(keyfilename)

ssh.connect(ssh_host, port=port, username=ssh_user, pkey=key)
```

But it turned out that some keys are RSA (not Ed25519).

Is there any way of reading SSH key of any type without using concrete implementation? Or maybe there's some way to determine the type?
Or the only way is to change all keys to known type?

Could not figure that of from [documentation](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/keys.html)

Before testing real configs I tried to read SSH key on my local PC from Jupyter.
When reading wrong type like this:

```
keyfilename = "%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/id_rsa"
keyfilename = os.path.expandvars(keyfilename)
privateKey = paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file(keyfilename)
```

It throws:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSHException                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 6
      4 keyfilename = "%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/id_rsa"
      5 keyfilename = os.path.expandvars(keyfilename)
----> 6 privateKey = paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file(keyfilename)
      7 display(key)
      8 display(privateKey)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py:421, in PKey.from_private_key_file(cls, filename, password)
    400 @classmethod
    401 def from_private_key_file(cls, filename, password=None):
    402     """
    403     Create a key object by reading a private key file.  If the private
    404     key is encrypted and ``password`` is not ``None``, the given password
   (...)
    419     :raises: `.SSHException` -- if the key file is invalid
    420     """
--> 421     key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
    422     return key

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\ed25519key.py:65, in Ed25519Key.__init__(self, msg, data, filename, password, file_obj)
     62     pkformat, data = self._read_private_key("OPENSSH", file_obj)
     64 if filename or file_obj:
---> 65     signing_key = self._parse_signing_key_data(data, password)
     67 if signing_key is None and verifying_key is None:
     68     raise ValueError("need a key")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\ed25519key.py:114, in Ed25519Key._parse_signing_key_data(self, data, password)
    112     pubkey = Message(message.get_binary())
    113     if pubkey.get_text() != self.name:
--> 114         raise SSHException("Invalid key")
    115     public_keys.append(pubkey.get_binary())
    117 private_ciphertext = message.get_binary()

SSHException: Invalid key
```

So I expect that it will throw the same thing when I try it with real configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `key_filename` parameter of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) instead of `pkey`.

---

If you want to use `pkey` for whatever reason, you would have to replicate what `SSHClient` does internally, when handling the `key_filename`. Roughly something like this (untested):

```
for pkey_class in (RSAKey, DSSKey, ECDSAKey, Ed25519Key):
    try:
        key = pkey_class.from_private_key_file(key_filename)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77128625/how-do-i-use-paramikos-pkey-read-private-key-to-fetch-keys-and-parse-them-fr?noredirect=1#comment135970765_77128625

dsa key breaks it since there is no SSHException:

consider this or anything that will combine both:
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An exception occurred: {e}")

Comment: @Jirafey Indeed, even if you pass a DSA key to `key_filename` parameter of `SSHClient.connect`, it fails with `ValueError("p*q must equal modulus.")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_key_class_name(filepath, passphrase):
    for pkey_class in (RSAKey, DSSKey, ECDSAKey, Ed25519Key):
        try:
            key = pkey_class.from_private_key_file(filepath, passphrase)
            class_name = str(pkey_class).split('.')[-1].rstrip(">'")

            return class_name

        except Exception as e:
            # print("An exception occurred: {}".format(e))
            pass

def proper_method_call(filepath, passphrase):
    key_class_name = get_key_class_name(filepath, passphrase)
    key_class = getattr(paramiko, key_class_name)
    key_method = getattr(key_class, "from_private_key_file")
    key = key_method(filepath, passphrase)
    return key

rsa_key_with_passphrase = proper_method_call(rsa_key_filename, key_passphrase)
```

pass it as an argument: `pkey=rsa_key_with_passphrase`

> Usage:

```
mid_cli = paramiko.SSHClient()
mid_cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
mid_cli.connect(hostname=host, username=username, password=password, pkey=rsa_key_with_passphrase)
io_tupple = mid_cli.exec_command('nc {} {}'.format(host, port))

proxy = ParaProxy(*io_tupple)

end_cli = paramiko.SSHClient()
end_cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

end_cli.connect(hostname=host, username=username, password=password, sock=proxy, pkey=rsa_key_with_passphrase)

commands = ['ls', 'echo $USER', 'hostname', 'echo close', 'bad_command']
for command in commands:
    print("Executing command:  ", command)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = end_cli.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.read().decode()
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print('Error:', err)
    else:
        print("Output:")
        print(output)

proxy.close()
time.sleep(.1)
mid_cli.close()
end_cli.close()
```